# What does "head on a snag" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following excerpt is from a Tomas Sowell's book "Black Rednecks & White Liberals"

“Talk about Northern steamers,” the fireman of a Mississippi steamboat
sneered to an eastern traveler in 1844,“it don’t need no spunk to navigate
them waters. You haint bust a biler in five years. But I tell you, stranger, it
takes a man to ride one of these half alligator boats, **head on a snag**, high pressures, valve soldered down, 600 souls on board & in danger of going to
the devil.”

TFD def for "**snag**"
b. A tree or a part of a tree that is sunken in or protrudes above a body of water and is a danger to navigation.

TFD def for **head-on**
b. A tree or a part of a tree that is sunken in or protrudes above a body of water and is a danger to navigation.
..or
2. In direct conflict, in open opposition, as in They decided to meet the opposition head on.

Does it mean to be facing a protruding tree in the water directly. I don't understand why the fireman in question would brag in this was because you'd have to avoid such an obstacle while being at the helm of such a boat.

Comment: He's bragging about his courage in working on a boat in dangerous conditions.  Presumably it means '[with the boat's] head [caught] on a snag'.

Comment: Oh, i get :) the head means the front of a ship here :) 21. (Nautical Terms) nautical
a. the front part of a ship or boat<source TFD> Thx:)

Comment: Or it might be a reference to a **head of steam** as he's bragging about "high pressures, [safety] valve soldered down". Possibly the steam pressure gauge is against the end stop [maybe called a snag].